# can't connect to google cloud using airflow 2.0 in docker with json key file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am trying to setup a GCP connection with apache airflow 2.0 in docker from MAC OS using JSON key file, I got this error when I trigger the DAG:

ERROR - [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/airflow_docker/plugins/key.json'

is there some configuration I need to set up in docker?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue like not able to create a bigquery connection from Airflow UI.

Comment: I actually don't remember, I think I've managed to do it somehow, but this project was discontinued so I don't know what I did, if I'll get back to this I will make sure to post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file `key.json` is really located at that place because it seems it isn't. You can do that by "debugging" your docker image like this:

- `docker run -it --rm --entrypoint sh <name-of-image>`
  this command allows you to access the image through the shell. That way you'll be able to see if the file is really located in that path. Do some `ls` operations in that path and others to locate where the key.json file really is

Comment: I tried running ls -la while in the IDE and I see the file in the path:
`(airflow_docker) user-pro:plugins user$ ls -la
total 8
drwxr-xr-x@  3 user  staff    96 Nov 29 10:40 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 user  staff   384 Dec 31 12:57 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff  2366 Nov 23 11:59 key.json
(airflow_docker) user-pro:plugins user$`

Comment: One thing I've noticed now, is that the path doesn't seem right -> `Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/airflow_docker/plugins/key.json`.This path is of your computer disk and not from the airflow docker image.

Comment: The path should be something like this `airflow/plugins/key.json`

Comment: Maybe it's best if you post here the dockerfile so I can help you better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue is that it's missing the volume mapping in your docker-compose.yaml

```
  volumes:
    ...
    - /Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/airflow_docker/plugins/:/opt/airflow/plugins
```

Comment: I think that exactly what happens but I lack the knowledge on how to map it

Comment: I think that exactly what happens but I lack the knowledge on how to map it, is this what I should input in the docker-compose.yaml? (the last line)?    `build:
    context: .
  environment:
  &airflow-common-env
  AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    .
    .
    .
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - /Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/airflow_docker/plugins/opt/airflow/plugins`

Comment: If you use the boilerplate docker-compose file provided by Airflow, you just need to create a directory `plugins` in the same level as that docker-compose file, and inside the `plugins` paste your `key.json` and you won't even need to change the docker-compose

Comment: Regarding your question ideally you shouldn't. Use the approach I've said the coment before. But if that doesn't work, then try this way

Comment: that is what I did and it is not finding the file... I created a folder plugins and saved the key.json

Comment: okay, then try to locate in your code (DAG, or configuration) where are you referencing the string -> "/Users/my_user/PycharmProjects/airflow_docker/plugins/key.json", because that path is definitly invalid

Comment: I don't reference this json file anywhere in my DAG. I saw a lecture when you set up a connection for GCP through accessing the key.json stored on your local machine and it worked. I tried doing the same after installing Airflow in docker and it doesn't work. I'm sure some configuration is missing, but since I don't have knowledge in docker I don't know how to fix it

Comment: ok, just to understand better your issue: how are you doing the GCP connection setup? are you doing it manually? or via dockerfile

Comment: I'm doing it manually in the DAG and I use the Connection tab in the Airflow webserver: I set up the key file path and the name of the GCP project. I've managed to fix the path as per your suggestion, and the error disappeared,now I face a different error with connection denied. So you helped me! Thank you! Although now not clear why permission is denied, this key works.